# I moved a wordpress website to my server and the home page shows up but why not any other pages?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am re-designing someone's Wordpress website and moslty need to change the CSS  I wanted to move his entire website over to my server in a new sub-folder in order to work on it and then I will move it back when I'm done.

I downloaded the entire site. Exported the database And then moved it to my server and uploaded the files and created a new database and imported it.

Then I used this to change the database to the correct directory: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Now I can login to the Wordpress dashboard, and the home page shows up but none of the other pages.  The other pages show the correct directory, is this a database problem?  How do I fix it?

Comment: have you set the paramlink setting in wordpress?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [wordpress.se]

Comment: You should use a plugin like WordPress Duplicator to move your website. Never had any problems using it.

Comment: Yes it was permalinks thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We dont know about your setup but there are 3 things that can cause this.

1. Goto settings> permalink and click on "Save Settings"
2. If the above doesn't work goto wp-config and add

   ```
   define('WP_HOME',    'http://example.com');
   define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com');
   ```
3. Check your .htaccess for base directory path, if your site is in a
   subdirectory you should replace it with /subdirectory

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you need to check.

1. check whether you have configured mod_rewrite in your server in  httpd.conf file.

check whether you have this line in httpd.conf file

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

2. check whether you have configured the permalinks through the admin panel.

Comment: Yes it was permalinks thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please update your permalinks. Under settings.