# Pages other than the home are not working after moving a Wordpress website to a subdomain

Tags: wordpress, data-migration

I have a wordpress website running on http://example.com and I moved it to a subdomain http://dev.example.com

After searching for useful information on stackoverflow, everything on the home page http://dev.example.com is running fine (path to logo, path to pages changed correctly, menu url changed...etc)

The issue I have is that pages like http://dev.example.com/my-page-title are not working ("*The requested URL /my-page-title/ was not found on this server*")!

What it may be the missing step so all my pages display correctly?

This is a resume of what I already did:

- I added those 2 lines to `wp-config.php`

  `define('WP_HOME','http://dev.example.com');
  define('WP_SITEURL','http://dev.example.com');`
- I made a search for "http://www.example.com" and replace with  "http://www.dev.example.com" using those 2 plugins:

  - https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls
  - https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace
- I can login to wp-admin
- I manually updated "siteurl" and "home" rows in "wp-options" with this value "http://dev.example.com".
- Already asked questions like [I moved a wordpress website to my server and the home page shows up but why not any other pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623006/i-moved-a-wordpress-website-to-my-server-and-the-home-page-shows-up-but-why-not) does not fix my issue.

Comment: Have you flushed your permalinks?

Comment: @spartacus Yes I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution https://github.com/wp-sync-db/wp-sync-db

> A WordPress plugin that lets you push, pull, and sync database tables
>   between WordPress installations.

Direct link to the zip plugin: https://github.com/afragen/github-updater/releases